# creating an object for delegation in java

Tags: java, object, delegation

here is a part of code that I found while searching for delegation. I did not understand a part. Do we have to create an object for delegation? Or we can use it only with the a variable typeof the class the we want the use method of?

```
public class Point {
    private double xCoord;
    private double yCoord;

    public double getXCoord(){
        return xCoord;
    }

    public double getYCoord(){
        return yCoord;
    }
}

public class Circle {
    /*
    Is it a variable defined type of Point?
    Is it possible or should it have been defined as below.
    What is the difference?
    */
    private Point center;
    // Point center = new Point();

    public double getCenterX(){
        return center.getXCoord(); // Delegation
    }

    public double getCenterY(){
        return center.getYCoord(); // Delegation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Is it a variable defined type of Point?**

It's a variable, but at this point, it's not initialised (an empty variable).

**Is it possible or should it have been defined as below?**

You must initialise your variable (Here, create a constructor, initialise your variable and initialise the xCoord and yCoord vars.

```
public class Point {
    private double xCoord;
    private double yCoord;

    public double getXCoord(){
        return xCoord;
    }

    public double getYCoord(){
        return yCoord;
    }
}

public class Circle {
    /*
        Is it a variable defined type of Point?
        Is it possible or should it have been defined as below.
        What is the difference?
    */
    private Point center;
    // Point center = new Point();

    public Circle(double x, double y) {    //    Constructor
        center = new Point();              //    Initialise variable
        center.xCoord = x;                 //    Set x
        center.yCoord = y;                 //    Set y
    }

    public double getCenterX(){
        return center.getXCoord(); // Delegation
    }

    public double getCenterY(){
        return center.getYCoord(); // Delegation
    }
}
```

**What is the difference?**

A difference between what ?

Comment: as I've seen in another examples we should create an object to use delegation but in this case there is a variable defined but not initialised . Should İ initialise it to an object with new keyword? or is this situtation  okay? I asked about the difference between the way it is now and  the initialised to an object as in the comment line?

Comment: You must initialise your variable if you want to use it. In your example, your variable **center** is set, but not initialised. So, if you call **getCenterX()**, you'll get a **NullPointerException**

Comment: Okay I see. Other than this I have to initialise it to a new object right?

Comment: yes, initialise the variable and set **xCoord** and **yCoord**